# Recursively move certain folders to other folders of the same name

Tags: mv

I have the following structure:

```
dir1
 - subdir0
   - subfile00
   - subfile01
 - subdir1
   - subfile10
   - subfile11
 - file0
 - file1

dir2
 - subdir0
   - subfile00
   - subfile01
   - custom_file
 - subdir1
   - subfile10
   - subfile11
   - custom_file
```

I want to be able to move all the contents of `dir1` to `dir2` recursively but not delete `custom_file` in each folder.

I can script something that lists all of the files and move them individually but I was hoping the `mv` command had some option for this. Does anybody know of a clever command line trick for this?

Comment: Whatever you end up coming up with, back up.  I also suggest using `cp` instead of `mv` - you can make some pretty bad mistakes with both but `cp` is generally safer

Comment: `rsync dir1 dir2` will do, followed by (if you're satisfied all has gone well) `rm -r dir1`.